# Why two partition deleted while I chose one (fdisk)?

Tags: partitioning, fdisk

I selected one partition to delete in fdisk but as you see the 3rd partition which is swap is deleted too, why?

```
Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048 12584959 12582912   6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       12587006 20969471  8382466   4G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       12587008 20969471  8382464   4G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Command (m for help): d
Partition number (1,2,5, default 5): 2

Partition 2 has been deleted.

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 10 GiB, 10737418240 bytes, 20971520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd2dfe316

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 12584959 12582912   6G 83 Linux

Command (m for help):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/dev/sda2` was an [extended partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#Extended_partition) and `/dev/sda5` was a logical partition residing *inside* of it. You can see that the Start and End positions of `/dev/sda5` overlap with `/dev/sda2`.

If this is not what you intended, you can still quit `fdisk` without applying changes by using the `q` command.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `/dev/sda5` is your only logical partition inside `/dev/sda2`, which is a extended partition. So by removing your extended partition, your logical partition will be removed as well.